# How to convert epoch time value to local time?

Tags: python, date, epoch

Issue is how to pass the numeric value of epoch time and convert it to local time in each line.

Input File: `log_data.csv`

```
id: 535,    epoch_time: 1611773844,    nsecs: 158737495, state: 2,status: 1
id: 536,    epoch_time: 1611773844,    nsecs: 258731299, state: 2,status: 1
id: 537,    epoch_time: 1611773844,    nsecs: 358585677, state: 4,status: 3
id: 538,    epoch_time: 1611773844,    nsecs: 458462033, state: 2,status: 1
```

Code snippet:

```
import datetime

def time(data):
 fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
 t = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(s)/1000.)
 print t.strftime(fmt)

def read_comlumn():
 for line in open("log_cleaning_3_final.log"):
     columns = line.split(',')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `csv` module and start from this

```
import csv
import datetime

def convert(data):
  fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
  t = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(data)/1000.)
  return t.strftime(fmt)

with open('log_cleaning_3_final.log', 'r') as f:
    csv_data = csv.reader(f)
    csv_lines = list(csv_data)

for line in csv_lines:
  line[1] = convert(line[1].split(':')[1].strip())

with open('log_cleaning_3_final.log', 'w') as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f)
  writer.writerows(csv_lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

You never really said what you want to do with the converted data — so I guessed and the code below writes it out to a file named `log_cleaning_3_final.log`. I also think you didn't mention what version of of Python you're using, but I suspect it's 2.x and have written the code so it works in that version.

```
from collections import OrderedDict as odict
import datetime

def time(data):
    t = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(data)/1000.)
    return t.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

def read_columns(filename):
    columns = []
    with open(inp_filename) as inp:
        for line in inp:
            row = dict([map(str.strip, col.strip().split(':')) for col in line.split(',')])
            row['epoch_time'] = time(row['epoch_time'])  # Convert to local time.
            columns.append(row)
    return columns

def write_columns(cols, filename):
    fieldnames = 'id epoch_time nsecs state status'.split()
    with open(filename, 'w') as outp:
        for row in cols:
            line = odict([(fieldname, row[fieldname]) for fieldname in fieldnames])
            line = ', '.join('{}: {}'.format(k, v) for k, v in line.items())
            outp.write(line + '\n')


cols = read_columns("log_data.csv")
write_columns(cols, "log_cleaning_3_final.log")
print('done')
```

Contents of the `log_cleaning_3_final.log` output file after running the above:

```
id: 535, epoch_time: 1970-01-19 07:42:53, nsecs: 158737495, state: 2, status: 1
id: 536, epoch_time: 1970-01-19 07:42:53, nsecs: 258731299, state: 2, status: 1
id: 537, epoch_time: 1970-01-19 07:42:53, nsecs: 358585677, state: 4, status: 3
id: 538, epoch_time: 1970-01-19 07:42:53, nsecs: 458462033, state: 2, status: 1
```